# Hadoop find all documents that contain a list of words

Tags: hadoop

I realize this could be done on a single machine using a HashMap<String, SortedSet> then an intersection of all document names, however am curious how Hadoop would solve this problem. Can anyone explain the general process?

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you'd rather use Elasticsearch for text searching, but Hadoop still operates on files and inputstreams, so you'd pass a substring function into a mapreduce command, and search text like normal.

You should not use a hashmap because there's no real need to store any data to find substrings in a block of text.